# Plotting a string column of format hh:mm:ss as histogram to get count of observation between 12 AM and 3 PM in R

Tags: r, time, plotly, histogram

I have a dataset with a column in string of format hh:mm:ss. I want to create a histogram based on this column in such a way that I can visualize the number of observations between 12 AM and 3 PM in R.

```
plot_ly(x = (as.numeric(data$Time) * 1000), type = "histogram") %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(type="date", tickformat="%H:%M:%S"))
```

I tried plotting using Plotly but the x-axis is in a different format than expected. Please give suggestions.

[image]

Comment: It would make it easier to help you if you add a snippet of your data to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be the use of the hms library

```
library("hms")
```

As there was no data provided I generated some random data for an easier understanding. The as_hms() function transforms the values as a difftime vector with a custom class

```
Count <- c(10,20,30,100,110,110,20,30,50,30)
Time <- c('12:02:01','12:07:38','12:30:42','12:57:21','13:01:09','13:38:36','13:48:43','13:51:33','14:50:22','14:59:59')

Time = as_hms(c(Time))

data = data.frame(Count, Time)
```

With ggplot you can now easily create an histogram with the number of observations. And if you need explicitly a plotly visualization you can achieve this with the library ggplotly.

```
p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Time, y=Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")


ggplotly(p)
```

[image]